Python-Spark version compatibility
Is it true Python version 3.12.4 is not compatible with spark 3.5.1? While running pyspark in the terminal I am getting a whole lot of issues, I am starting with checking if the language integration is compatible or not. If not, then I'll go ahead with checking for different issues.
To setup the environment for running pyspark.
